# Driver is unable to find elements using CSS Selector, or XPATH . (Selenium Web Scraping)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web, webdriver

I've been trying to scrape data from a website run using iCIMS, however whenever I try to use quite basic CSS selectors, or XPATHS the program is unable to find it.
This is my code:

```
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options,service=service)
driver.get("https://careers-omrf.icims.com/jobs/search?hashed=-625950327&mobile=false&width=1359&height=500&bga=true&needsRedirect=false&jan1offset=-360&jun1offset=-300")
time.sleep(10)
a = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a.iCIMS_Anchor")
```

Whenever I run this block of code, `a` becomes an empty list. I've even tried using a CSS Selector of just the element `h2`, and it still returns an empty list which is very weird.

Answer (score 0):

**Root cause of the issue:** The desired elements are inside an [IFRAME](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/frames/) (See below screenshot).

[image]

**Solution:** In such cases, you need to switch into the context of `IFRAME` and then perform the actions you want. Check the code below with explanation:

```
driver.get("https://careers-omrf.icims.com/jobs/search?hashed=-625950327&mobile=false&width=1359&height=500&bga=true&needsRedirect=false&jan1offset=-360&jun1offset=-300")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Below like will switch into the context of IFRAME
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "icims_content_iframe")))

# Store desired elements into variable a
a = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.iCIMS_Anchor")))

# Print length of a
print(len(a))

# Below line is to come out of IFRAME
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

**Imports required:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Console output:**

```
20

Process finished with exit code 0
```